# Limits Application Question (Ratio Test Proof)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm watching a video on ratio test proof and am confused about a statement.

For an infinite series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ $a_n > 0$, and $$L = \lim_{n\to
\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$

If $L>1$, pick $\epsilon$, such that $L - \epsilon > 1$.

The video states that by definition of limit, there must be an $N$ such that for $n \geq N$, $a_{n+1}/a_n > L - \epsilon$. Why is this?

My process: We know L = lim as n -> infinity of (a sub [n+1])/(a sub n), so by definition of limit |(a sub [n+1])/(a sub n)-L| < L - epsilon, leading to 1)(a sub [n+1])/(a sub n)-L < epsilon or 2) (a sub [n+1])/(a sub n)-L > epsilon, but how do we know which of these is true?

Similarly, the video also says: If L<1, pick epsilon, such that L + epsilon < 1. And that by definition of limit, there must be an N such that for n>=N, (a sub [n+1])/(a sub n) < L + epsilon. For probably the same reason, why is this?

(Note: Please explain at my level, my level is multivariable calculus)

(video in question:https://youtu.be/2gi7pyQNxbM?si=3hvx0cegO5fO5q8D&t=257)

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I started editing your post already)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $ \lvert a _ { n + 1 } / a _ n - L \rvert < \epsilon $, this means that $ a _ { n + 1 } / a _ n - L < \epsilon $ AND $ a _ { n + 1 } / a _ n - L > - \epsilon $.  (For an absolute value to be close to zero, the number must not be too large *and* must not be too small.)  So you don't have to decide which is true; the proof only needs one of these, but both are available.  (And notice that it's $ - \epsilon $ in the second one.)

You can also write it as $$ - \epsilon < \frac { a _ { n + 1 } } { a _ n } - L < \epsilon \text , $$ and then the proof only needs the left-hand inequality (but both are true).

The second half is similar, except that this time, the proof only needs the right-hand inequality.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it was an OR instead of an AND.

Comment: If you have $|u|>a$, then you get an OR: $u>a$ or $u<-a$. Even for $|u|=a$, you mostly get an OR: $u=a$ or $u=-a$, and $a\geq0$; but the $a\geq0$ part is usually obvious. But for $|u|<a$, you get an AND: $-a<u<a$. (And the same rules work for weak inequalities $\leq,\geq$ too.)

Answer (score 3):

> The video states that by definition of limit, there must be an $N$ such that for $n\geq N$, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} > L - \epsilon$. Why is this?

Because the definition of a limit is this:

> Let $b_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. Then, we say that $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$$ if and only if, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\in \mathbb N$, we know that if $n\geq N$, then $|b_n-L|<\epsilon$. Written with symbols, that means
> $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n\iff \forall\epsilon>0\exists N\in\mathbb N\forall n\in\mathbb N: n\geq N\implies |b_n-L|<\epsilon$$

Simply apply this definitio to $b_n=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, and you get more or less the claim from the video. What you really get is that $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-L|<\epsilon$, but that directly implies the claim in the video.

Comment: I understand the statement |b_n-L|<epsilon from the definition of limits, but how do we get rid of the absolute value and choose one of the two possibilities? either  b_n-L<epsilon or  b_n-L>epsilon

Comment: @Pheonix $|b_n-L|<\epsilon$ is equivalent to $-\epsilon<b_n-L\land b_n-L<\epsilon$.